# ERROR: Maximum message size quota for incoming messages(65536) has been exceeded

Tags: soap, sandbox, c#

Tried to retrieve an sobject:

```
  DescribeSObjectResult leadObjDesc;
  try
  {
    _sfClient.describeSObject(_sesHeader, null, null, "Lead", out leadObjDesc);
  }
```

Got this exception:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

The config for the Enterprise WSDL I'm using looks like:

```
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
             maxArrayLength="200000000"
             maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
      <binding name="SoapBinding">
        <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
      <binding name="SoapBinding2">
        <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
      <endpoint address="https://cs2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFR00000008TUB"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding"
          contract="SFTest.Soap" name="Soap" />
      <endpoint address="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DF50000000057v"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding2"
          contract="SFEnterpriseService.Soap" name="Soap1" />
  </client>
```

I can't seem to figure out why. Thoughts?

Comment: I suspect it's because you need to place the maxReceivedMessageSize property on *each binding* in order for it to work. But I'm not a C# expert.

Answer (score 1):

You have your configuration setup incorrectly it should look like this.

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="SoapBinding" allowCookies="true"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
         maxBufferSize="20000000"
         maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
    <security mode="Transport" />
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
         maxArrayLength="200000000"
         maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
  </binding>
  <binding name="SoapBinding2" allowCookies="true"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
         maxBufferSize="20000000"
         maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
    <security mode="Transport" />
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
         maxArrayLength="200000000"
         maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
  <client>
  <endpoint address="https://cs2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFR00000008TUB"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding"
      contract="SFTest.Soap" name="Soap" />
  <endpoint address="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DF50000000057v"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding2"
      contract="SFEnterpriseService.Soap" name="Soap1" />
</client>
```

Each named binding corresponds to a client bindingConfiguration. The settings for things like maxReceivedMessageSize are set per configuration.